# Jboss Service depending on JNDI resource

Tags: service, jboss, jndi, mbeans, depends

I have written a Jboss4 MBean which relies on other JNDI resource named XAOracleDS and defined in an xml datasource file (*-ds.xml). But when I restart my JBoss instance,  I have a

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: XAOracleDS not bound

due to the implementation of my service. I tried to fix this by updating my jboss-service.xml file adding a dependency to the Jboss naming service

```
...
<depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
...
```

, but it didn't work.
Here is my jboss-service.xml

```
 <server>
<classpath codebase="lib" archives="scheduler-plugin.jar" />

<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler"  name="DefaultDomain:service=MigrationScheduler">
    <attribute name="StartAtStartup">true</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulableClass">MyScheduler</attribute>
    <attribute name="InitialStartDate">NOW</attribute>
    <attribute name="InitialRepetitions">1</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulePeriod">1000</attribute>
    <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
</mbean>
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue a while back and not 100% sure whether it applies to you. Found that the files are deployed alphabetically. So try renaming your *-ds.xml files with say abc-ds.xml and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this solution by prefixing my *-ds.xml with aaa, but I had the same error.